# Creat a group of users in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm developing an android application and i'm not really good with PHP and MySQL, so i'm not really sure how can i achieve this. I have followed one tutorial for writing a good RESTFUL Api. I have three tables for now in MySql,

1. users
2. groups
3. user_groups

   This is the schema of users table

   `id (primary key)
   name (varchar)
   ...
   ...
   api_key (varchar)`

I'm generating api key for every new registered user. 
With that api key, the user can create a new group.

My question is how could i assign other users to that new group, without sending Authorization api key or how could it be done?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but if a user wants to join a group, a request should be sent by that user to the API, and the request should have the user's API-KEY to allow the request.

Comment: Exactly, that's what i need. So i should take somehow api key from the user who has already created a group and with that api key send a request. Should i add some new field in my table.

Comment: who will add the other user to the group? the group creator or the user himself? if the user adds himself, then you need his api-key not the other one, right?

Comment: User could send a request for joining the group and the group creator also can invite someone to join the group.

Comment: good, any request to the API should be done using the caller user api-key, regardless who created the group.

Comment: I understand what you are saying to me, but the problem is that i don't know how to that. I have one method which is assigning the group creator to the table `user_groups` after he creates a new group. And in that table i have two fields `user_id` and `group_id`. Now i guess if i want more users to join the group, they will get group_id of existed group and they will join the group using api-key of the group creator?

Comment: no, they will join it using there api-key, a call to a certain endpoint say `http://server/api/join_group`, and in that table you will insert caller id, group id